# Induction, horses of the same color and manual checking of all $n$'s

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I suppose that you know the induction proof why all horses are of the same color and how it fails on $n=1$.

(just in case a few links: https://web.stanford.edu/~dntse/classes/cs70_fall09/cs70-2_notes3.pdf
https://www.math.hmc.edu/funfacts/ffiles/30002.8.shtml)

The question is:

The proof(reasoning) fails on the step with n=1. For all other it is correct. But the proof by induction (not the strong one) doesn't require us to check all values of $n$. We just need to show some correct base case(0 or 1 in this problem) and prove that if something is true for $n$ is also true for $n+1$, which was done in this case (as I understand it).

Please share your thoughts about this, I've searched for several hours but wasn't been able to find any explanation.

Comment: You should make the question self-contained, people can't be arsed with opening links and switching between windows, plus links might die. I didn't read that particular proof, but I suggest you check the proof specifically for the case $n=2$.

Comment: I just want to make question more concise

Comment: Typically you have something like $H_1$ shown to be true and $\forall n\, H_n \Rightarrow H_{n+1}$ and can then use induction.  Here you have  $H_1$ shown to be true and $\forall n\ge 2\, H_n \Rightarrow H_{n+1}$ but $H_1 \nRightarrow H_2$ so the induction chain is broken

Comment: The induction step requires that the statement must be true for $n+1$ whenever it is true for $n$, the step must work for every $n$, otherwise the induction does not work.

Comment: Yes, but we usually don't check any values of $n$ besides the base case, so how we choose when and what values to check?

Comment: The statement for $n=1$ is somewhat "artificial". If we compare one element (to itself), it must of course be the same. The induction step however must compare at least two elements. (We assume that horse $1$ and horse $2$ have the same colour). This cannot be jusitified with the case $n=1$ because here we do only have one horse. Therefore, the induction step cannot be applied from $n=1$ to $n=2$.

Comment: Why? We can choose whatever set size we like, even 0, and the proposition that all horses are of the same color will be true.

Comment: But if you don't like it the set of 1 horse is perfectly legitimate set. Proving the sum of integers uses base case of 1 and it's ok. I see you idea and it's reasonable, but I think that formally we can use 0 or 1 size sets here.

Comment: @VladimirKotrovskiy True, but since the comparison is artifical (although mathematically correct) , we cannot conclude the case $n=2$ because we cannot properly formulate the assumption for $n=1$. In the case $n=1$ , we only have the trivial equation $x_1=x_1$. But the induction hypothesis needs $x_1=x_2$, so we already need two elements, but the case $n=1$ only tells us that equality holds for one element.

Comment: To make it clearer : $x_1=x_1$ and $x_1=x_1$ only implies $x_1=x_1$, so nothing new. But $x_1=x_2$ and $x_2=x_3$ implies $x_1=x_3$, so a new equality due to the transitivity.

Comment: Proving sum of $n$ integers = $(n*(n-1))/2$ we take base case as 0 or 1, what is the difference?

Answer (score 1):

It's all about the logic and the structure of the argument. That is, if you carefully lay out the logic you may find that the step does not work for certain $n$. So it is not as if *beforehand* we say "Hmm, I wonder if the step will go through for $n=117$ ... I better check!", but rather *as you go through the proof* you may find that some part of the argument just cannot be completed.

In particular, when in the horses argument you first take out horse $a$, and later on horse $b$, then you can only logically infer that all the horses in the two sets of remaining horses $S \setminus \{a \}$ and $S \setminus \{ b \}$ are the same color, and that would require for there to be a third horse $c$ that is in both of those sets ... so when there is no third horse, as when $n=2$, you can't make that logical step.  Of course, when there is a third horse, as when $n>2$, you can.

So the structure of the argument will dictate that there may be different cases to check, and which specific ones. Of course, in many inductive proofs the structure of the argument is such that no further cases need to be separated, and the logic really does work for all $n$. It all depends on what specifically you are trying to prove, and how you are trying to prove it.

Comment: I totally agree with it and was thinking the similar way. But then how do we know for sure that the proof by induction is correct? In this case, we looked into the problem and find some discrepancy. But what if the problem is more complex and we can't easily find such inconsistency even if it exists? For me, something may be considered a proof only when it's 100% correct, but following the above reasoning, we can think of a situation that somebody after a while will find a case for which the proof doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

> But the proof by induction (not the strong one) doesn't require us to check all values of $n$. We just need to prove that if something is true for $n$ is also true for $n+1$, which was done in this case...

This is wrong. Induction requires a base case (generally this is checking whether argument holds for the smallest possible number that is given in the argument in weak induction). Then in inductive assumption, we assume **the argument holds for all** $n$ greater than the $n$ value we used in base case; then show whether it is true for $n+1$. It is not just $n$ and $n+1$, we need a base case and we also need to assume for all $n$ before proving for $n+1$.

Further information, I saw a good explanation in university, since it can be helpful, I will also share that one:

> Let $P_0, P_1,P_2,...$ be statements. Then in classic induction:
>
> If $P_0$ holds (base case) and each $P_n$ implies $P_{n+1}$ ($P_n \implies P_{n+1}$, inductive assumption), then $P_n$ holds for all $n$.

Comment: What is the reason for downvoting?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I didn't mention the base case (corrected), but I'm aware of it (it can be n = 0 or n=1). I understand that we make the assumption that $P_n$ must hold for all values $< n$ in case of strong induction, and logically in case of simple induction. B.t.w. from wikipedia:

*The proof consists of two steps:*

*The base case: prove that the statement holds for the first natural number n. Usually, n = 0 or n = 1.*

*The inductive step: prove that, if the statement holds for some natural number n, then the statement holds for n + 1.*

I ask another thing: in proving by induction we generally don't check the correctness of $P$ at specific values of $n$, but we did it in this case. Why?